# Does the PC muscle recover faster in comparison to the other muscles?

Tags: muscle-recovery

I often read "if you exercise your PC muscles every day you will see great results". This is counter-intuitive to me, having been working out for many years. I know for sure that if I don't rest enough, the worse the results. So why many people recommend exercising the PC muscle differently (every day)?

Comment: Could you flesh out the question a bit? It's somewhat unclear where you're getting these quotes from, and they seem a bit out of context.

Comment: Do not have the time to search now but if you do, search for how to train the PC muscle, 1 out of 3 people will say to work it out every day. Check David Brown's first part of the answer. It is exactly what they advise us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say because most of the (non-scientific) advice I've seen around the web is "endurance" stuff. So start with x squeezes every day and build up to 600 per day or whatever.

If you exercise like that you're not really gaining strength (at least after a certain point), but simply building up endurance. So it's kinda like running longer and longer every day (at roughly the same pace) instead of weight lifting with progressing difficulty for strength/mass gains.

To bring my point home, the way most people exercise their PC muscle can be done on a daily basis. But if you truly trained your PC muscle to reach peak strength (which is definitely what you need if you're after the male multi-orgasm thing), then you'd get better results with longer recovery periods. Because, at least to my knowledge, the PC muscle responds to training no differently than any other muscle in our body.